# Was Jesus a Buddhist monk named Issa?

Tags: comparative-religion

As per BBC documentary Jesus Christ was a Buddhist monk named Issa. According to documentary Jesus was not crucified and he was trained as Buddhist monk.Further to that Jesus tomb situated in Kashmir Pradesh. How is this valid? (E.g Buddhism is older than Christianity and more possibility of extract Buddhist teaching to Christianity.) If it so what are the similarity of teaching of Buddha and preaching of Jesus?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104357/discussion-on-question-by-danuka-shewantha-was-jesus-a-buddhist-monk-named-issa).

Comment: There isn't any valid reason to close the answer and to call it off-topic. Off-imagination or "off-sources" might fill the validation reason.

Answer (score 3):

**How is this valid?**

It is not.

The video titled [Jesus was a Buddhist Monk BBC Documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAaW6BYhfNM) (on YouTube) is actually a copy of this: [Did Jesus Die? (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3091044/).

According to Wikipedia:

> [Suggestions of influences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_Christianity#Suggestions_of_influences)
>
> The suggestion that an adult Jesus traveled to India and was influenced by Buddhism before starting his ministry in Galilee was first made by Nicolas Notovitch in 1894 in the book The Unknown Life of Jesus Christ which was widely disseminated and became the basis of other theories.[40][41] Notovitch's theory was controversial from the beginning and was widely criticized.[42][43] Once his story had been re-examined by historians, Notovitch confessed to having fabricated the evidence.

Here is something the BBC published in 2010:

> [Tourists flock to 'Jesus's tomb' in Kashmir](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/from_our_own_correspondent/8587838.stm)
>
> Professional historians tend to laugh out loud when you mention the notion that Jesus might have lived in Kashmir - but his tomb is now firmly on the tourist trail - and a growing number of credulous visitors believe that he was buried in the Rozabal shrine.
>
> And for those who scoff, remember that others have argued, just as implausibly, that Jesus came to Britain.

Answer (score -2):

I 100% agree with Jesus Christ learned Buddhism in the past. Jesus came to India to learn about Buddhism and copied some of Lord Buddha’s teachings and comments. Why some histories/ stories were hidden by some people?
Jesus Christ learned Buddhism, but haven’t learned the pure teachings of Buddha such as 
The Three Universal Truths;
The Four Noble Truths; and The Noble Eightfold Path that don’t have in both Mahayana Buddhism and Vajrayana Buddhism except Theravada Buddhism. As we know, there are three main branches of Buddhism, but come from one pure thing called Theravāda Buddhism. 
Jesus obviously did not learn directly from the Buddha because the Buddha lived hundreds of years, not just a century, before him. But he was obviously influenced by Buddhist teachings. Even a cursory examination of the teachings of Jesus can find numerous similarities to the teaching of Buddhism.
So who copied some of Lord Buddha’s messages n teachings❓❓And who was influenced by Lord Buddha’s teachings?

The Golden Rule 
Buddha: "Consider others as yourself." (Dhammapada 10:1) Jesus: "Do to others as you would have them do to you." (Luke 6:31)

Love others 
Buddha: Let your thoughts of boundless love pervade the whole world." (Sutta 
Nipata 149- 150) Jesus: This is my commandment that you love one another as I have loved you. (John 15:12)

Love your enemies 
Buddha: Overcome anger by love, overcome evil by good. Overcome the miser by giving, overcome the liar by truth. (Dhar &17.3) napada 1.5

Jesus: Love your enemies, do good to those who hate you, bless those who curse you, pray for those who abuse you. (Luke 6.27-30)

Turn the other cheek 
Buddha: "If anyone should give you a blow with his hand, with a stick, or with a knife, you should abandon any desires and utter no evil words." (Majjhima Nikaya 21:6) 
Jesus: "If anyone strikes you on the cheek, offer the other also." (Luke 6:29)

Help others 
Buddha: "If you do not tend to one another, then who is there to tend you? Whoever would tend me, he should tend the sick." (Vinaya, Mahavagga 8:26.3)

Jesus: "TrulyI tell you, just as you did not do it to one of the least of these, you did not do it to me." (Matthew 25:45)

Do not judge others 
Buddha: "The fault of others is easily perceived, but that of oneself is difficult to perceive; a man winnows his neighbour's faults like chaff, but his own fault he hides." (Dhammapada 252.) 
Jesus: "Judge not, that you be not judged. And why do you look at the speck in your brother's eye, but do not consider the plank in your own eye?" (Matthew 7:15)

Disdain wealth 
Buddha: "Let us live most happily, possessing nothing." (Dhammapada 15:4) 
Jesus: Blessed are you who are poor, for yours is the kingdom of God." (Luke 6:20)

Do not kill
Buddha: "Abandoning the taking of life, the ascetic Gautama dwells refraining from taking life, without stick or sword." Digha Nikaya 1:1.8) 
Jesus: "Put your sword back into its place; for all those who take the sword will perish by the sword." (Matthew 26:52)

Spread the word 
Buddha: "Teach the dharma which is lovely at the beginning, lovely in the middle, lovely at the end. Explain with the spirit and the letter in the fashion of Brahma. In this way you will be completely fulfilled and wholly pure." (Vinaya Mahavagga 1:11.1) 
Jesus: "Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, and teaching them to obey everything that I have commanded you." (Matthew 28:19-20).